# how is an HTTP request passed to a web framework?

Tags: http, web-frameworks

What's the typical way that HTTP requests/responses are exchanged between a web server and a web framework? E.g. if you have your website in Rails, but you're using Apache Server. Is it via named pipes, anonymous pipes, forking a process and putting the request in the argument vector, writing to a file, etc? I'm writing a web framework that starts with a fully-formed HTTP request (as opposed to reading a socket directly), and I would like to replicate the behavior of the most common frameworks in how they interact with a web server.

Comment: How an Apache HTTPD redirects a HTTP request to a Rails "container"? Is that your question?

Comment: I would look into the [Apache Module API](https://modules.apache.org/).

Comment: @acdcjunior well, it's not specific to Rails, and I'm not sure what the term "container" means in rails lingo. My question is, what's the most common way for an HTTP server to send and receive data to and from a web framework, assuming they're running as two separate processes on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the AJP protocol:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_JServ_Protocol

It was originally developed to make an Apache HTTP server sit in front of a Tomcat application server, but there is nothing specific to Java in the protocol, so you can reuse at least the concepts for your implementation.

One very nice thing about APJ is that it handles virtual hosts properly. The front end server passes the correct information to the back-end server so the latter can generate correct internal hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a technical documentation about the architecture of Phusion Passenger (Rails application server)

[Phusion - Architectural Overview](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Architectural%20overview.html)